# Finding the answer to an integral.

Tags: integration

Is there a solution in closed form for the following integral?

\begin{equation}
F = \int_a^b \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-\varepsilon_1}} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-\varepsilon_2}}\,dx
\end{equation}

Comment: What have you tried yourself? There is a very simple primitive function here... Also, what are $\varepsilon_1$ and $\varepsilon_2$? I hope/assume they are in the range so that everything is real?

Comment: Yes. Everything is real.
So, what is the answer to said integral?

Comment: I have written it in an answer, but I have not posted it yet. I wait for you to show some effort. What will you learn if you don't?

Comment: Congratulations! Of course someone left an answer (without any solution, so you did not learn anything). Now you can go on with your life...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming appropriate values for $a,b,\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2$: $F=2(\log(\sqrt{b-\varepsilon_1}+\sqrt{b-\varepsilon_2})-\log(\sqrt{a-\varepsilon_1}+\sqrt{a-\varepsilon_2}))$